# Java: Get Video file from Multipart POST request

Tags: java, android, rest, google-app-engine, jersey

I am POSTing a video file from my Android client to my server as a Multipart request. I need to write a server side method to receive the following request.

- I am using Jersey as the server side Framework

**My code is as follows:**

```
private void send_video_to_server(String videoPath) throws ParseException, IOException {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://MY_SERVER_URL/videos/postvideo");

        FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));
        StringBody title = new StringBody(titleBox.getText().toString());
        StringBody description = new StringBody(captionBox.getText().toString());

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("videoFile", filebodyVideo);
        reqEntity.addPart("title", title);
        reqEntity.addPart("description", description);
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        // DEBUG
        System.out.println( "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine( ) );
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity( );

        // DEBUG
        System.out.println( response.getStatusLine( ) );
        if (resEntity != null) {
            System.out.println( EntityUtils.toString( resEntity ) );
        } // end if

        if (resEntity != null) {
            resEntity.consumeContent( );
        } // end if

        httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( );
    }
```

How would I write the **SERVER** side code to **RECEIVE** the above request? **The Method Signature will be sufficient for the answer** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem exactly?
Dont know about Jersey, but the steps would be:

1) Write a servlet (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm)

2) Servlet input parameter HttpServletRequest contains getParts() method, where you would find your posted video...along with other parts if any

**EDIT**

Untested, but will this help you? You should be able to get the stream of the video data like this.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        Collection parts = req.getParts();
        for (Part part : parts) {
            //... determine if its a file part from content disposition for example
            InputStream is = part.getInputStream();
            //...work with your input stream
        }
    }
```

For detailed example, see how spring does it:
[See spring way](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.web/3.1.2/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java?av=f)

Comment: Shouldn't it be a POST method that takes in a multipart request?

Comment: @Earthling Yes well HttpServlet also has doPost method which you can override similarly to the doGet method. See [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-)

Comment: Thank you but I'm still confused as to how to receive the file from the request when it reaches the doPost? How do I encode the multipart request?

Comment: @Earthling See my edit, does this help you to get going?

Comment: And can I add the @Path("/postvideo") path to this method as well?